# Host for Wt C++ web framework, deplowment issue

Tags: c++, frameworks, web, host, wt

I was wondering if justhost.com would be good enough to host a Wt C++ website/app on. It does allow FTP and SSH access as http://richelbilderbeek.nl/CppWtDeployGlobalHosted.htm tells me a host should, but I am just looking to get more input, or if you know of a better host?

Answer (score 4):

I'd also ask them if you can install libraries on there, if not you'd have to compile yourself a giant static app, which could be a bit of annoying restriction.

It looks to me like their site is basically designed to host standard php style apps more than anything.

I use [slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com) and [Rackspace Cloud Servers](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/servers/).

The thing is they are full VPS's and give you full root access.

I would go with a true VPS plan, rather than a chroot style shared hosting plan, with ssh access added on top. The main problem would be neighbouring bloated applications using all the shared resources and giving you inconsistent performance.

Also with full root access, you can set up your app to start on boot, and sort out your own DB backup plan etc..

You still can get neighbours slowing you down on VPS accounts, but it's much reduced.

One thing I like with Witty is that my app running with 100 threads, even with the cheapest VPS plan it runs consistently and smooth up to 50 concurrent users (tested using [load impact](http://loadimpact.com/)) with hardly any load on the machine at all.

My general pro c++ statement: Some c# and java people say c++ is only really useful for embedded, low powered hardware. I'd like to add that it's also useful for VPSs. Although hardware power is always growing, with virtualization, there's always more cheaper lower powered plans coming out that c++ is perfect for.

I used to run php, perl and python web servers on VPSs but my C++ witty app really does leave them all in the dust performance wise. The idea being you can pay less per month to host a c++ Web site that scales really well, rather than rails or other interpreted or byte compiled languages.

Also, I used to use a larger, 4 GB Slice to do my compiling until I bought myself a decent 6 core home box. The 256 MB (the smallest plan) is no good for compiling, but excellent for running.